# What are junctions in a transistor and how does current flow in them?

Tags: transistors, npn, pn-junction

I want to clarify what "junctions" are in an NPN transistor and how current flows in them.

1. Is the area inside the blue circle considered the "BC" junction?

[image]

2. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor) as well as [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/528222/how-does-forward-biasing-of-both-junctions-in-bjt-leads-to-saturation), in saturated mode BE and BC are both forward biased, is this how the current would go through it in this case (blue arrows)? Note that I'm not talking about electron flow:

[image]

3. Now what if we are in forward-active mode in which case BE is still forward biased but BC is reverse biased, is this how the current moves then?

[image]

But this doesn't make sense to me as current in BC will be moving in the opposite direction of the circuit. What am I missing?

Comment: See if https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqr0T99taGY is of any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a transistor is operating in its *transistor* mode, the back-to-back diode model is not a good one. If the emitter is not connected, then the base and collector terminals act as a diode in every sense. Similarly if the collector is not connected, the base and emitter form a diode.

Semiconductors are normally insulators. They don't have electrons available for conduction the same way that metals do. Given a stimulus, some electrons can be raised to a state of conduction just like metals. Then if they encounter an electric field they will flow in the direction determined by the field.

In a transistor, think of the reversed biased collector base diode as a container of electrons that can vibrate but can't flow because it is reverse biased. When electrons are injected into the transistor they excite the local electrons to a level of conduction. The more base current the more conduction electrons that there are. *It is like a small stream opening a large door.*

Electrons then actually flow through the "reverse biased diode". This is why a transistor cannot be considered as back-to-back diodes when operating as a *transistor*.

> According to wikipedia as well as this post, in saturated mode BE and BC are both forward biased,...

\$V_{ce}\$ decreases because the current through the collector resistor increases. If there is current from collector to emitter, then the base voltage will be greater than the emitter voltage. In other words the base emitter diode is forward biased.
Normally the base collector diode is reverse biased. ( In transistor mode it is difficult to continue thinking of it as a diode, but it is done). \$V_{ce}\$ continues to decrease as \$V_{be}\$ increases until it is less than \$V_{be}\$. This is called saturation. The base voltage is greater than both the collector and emitter voltages meaning that they are both forward biased. The currents are as you show in Number 2.

It is hard to visualize this diode that isn't a diode.

While this description is very, very over-simplified perhaps it will be a helpful visualization.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not really, because the blue circle is drawn on a schematic symbol that represents the transistor, it does not depict how a transistor junction actually is built.
2. Correct
3. Incorrect. In forward active mode the collector current goes into C and out from E.

Comment: but wound't that be the same as the image under (2) ?

Comment: Yes. The currents go identically.

Comment: Well that just made things a lot worse. Then what's *reversed* exactly? the diodes?

Comment: The collector voltage can be higher or lower than base voltage. The other is called saturation, the other is called forward active. Difference is which way the BC junction is biased.

Comment: Right so as an example, in forward-active mode the  B–C junction is *reversed* according to the Wikipedia page. What does that mean? what's reversed? Does it just mean one has lower voltage then the other?

Comment: The BC voltage. In the other mode, it is reverse when compared to the other mode, no matter which way you look at the modes or voltages.

Comment: Thanks, one more things I wanted to ask about, based on this image https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/1/9/3/transistors-as-diodes.png a NPN can be thought of as two diodes connected to each other back to back. How can current flow from C to E in this case? current can't flow in that direction in a diode frmo C to B.

Comment: :/ why is this topic covered so confusing on the web. I would have written it differently.

Comment: That's because in NPN transistor the base is P type and C and E are N type so you have two PN junctions which are diodes BE and BC. But that's not how transistors work as they can't be thought as two back-to-back diodes so it is not an useful model for a transistor. However it is an somewhat useful model for the junctions, as it depicts the two diode junctions which is what you observe if you probe the transistor pins separately, maybe with a multimeter to check if it is damaged or to determine if it is NPN or PNP transistor, and just maybe figure out which terminal is E and C.

Comment: @Dan Because it's not two diodes back to back. Two diodes back to back being a BJT transistor is like saying that gluing a a piece of bread to the underside of a tabletop and placing a piece of bread on top of the table makes a sandwich. Semiconductors rely on the direct physical interaction between two materials so sticking a metal wire in between changes everything. You can't connect a piece of P and N silicon by a wire and make a diode either.

Comment: Also, another thing wrong about BJT = back-to-back diode is that you are probably assuming identical diodes, but remember that the thickness and doping of P and N silicon can be changed to whatever you want in a BJT and this really matters. There is also a lot of devil in the details. For example, a Schottky diode is a a junction between metal and silicon. But wait a minute...aren't the bondwires coming out from any semiconductor also metal and silicon? The answer is that you can make it a resistor or you can make a diode based on very particular details about the material and surface prep.

Comment: The reason you can have current flow through the reverse-biased base-collector junction in the "wrong" direction is because the charge carriers (electrons, in this case) are injected into the base from the forward-biased base-emitter junction.  But before they can recombine and cause current to flow into the base terminal, they encounter the base-collector depletion region and are pulled out of the base by its electric field, which causes/allows current to flow into the collector instead.   A few electrons do recombine in the base, which is where base current goes.